# Multiple Select with same table in MySQL doesn't work

Tags: mysql, select, multiple-select-query

i'm having a problem with my database's multiple selection. I need to do a select that returns a kind of table with some processed data, and it need to be ordered by day of month. To do this, i'm using multiple select's issue of mysql. This is my code:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM `table` WHERE `type`=1                                                                                AS 'Total',
    (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM `table` WHERE `type`=1 and `status` = 0 and `status_cancel` = 0                                       AS 'Open',
    (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM `table` WHERE `type`=1 and `status_cancel` = 1                                                        AS 'Cancel',
    (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM `table` WHERE `type`=1 and `date_finish` is not null and `status_cancel` = 0                          AS 'Finish',
    (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM `table` WHERE `type`=1 and `result` >= 0 and  `date_finish` is not null and `status_cancel` = 0       AS 'Win',
    (SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM `table` WHERE `type`=1 and `result` < 0 and `date_finish` is not null and `status_cancel` = 0         AS 'Loss'
```

Now it's returning the total of all rows in my table, but i can't do this return it grouped by day, help me, please!

The result must be like this:

[Result that i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pigxQ.png)

Comment: More information is needed. What is the full schema of the table? What is the output you are looking for? Give a sample output. Your query should only return one row but it looks like you want more than one. What do you mean ordered by day of month?

Comment: When asking SQL query questions, please run `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for all tables referenced in the query, and include the result in your question. That'll give us information so we don't have to guess at your columns, data types, indexes, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are saying how can I group by date when my queries are all amounting to sub queries.  I would change it to be case statements for that. Try something like this

```
SELECT  DATE(date_finish) as `date`, count(*) as 'Total', 
        SUM(CASE WHEN `status` = 0 AND `status_cancel` = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Open',
        SUM(CASE WHEN `status_cancel` = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Cancel',
        SUM(CASE WHEN `date_finish` is not null and `status_cancel` = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Finish',
        SUM(CASE WHEN `result` >= 0 AND `date_finish` is not null AND `status_cancel` = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Win',
        SUM(CASE WHEN `result` < 0 AND `date_finish` is not null AND `status_cancel` = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'Loss'
from `table` 
WHERE `type` = 1 
group by DATE(date_finish)
```

TEST: http://rextester.com/HCRIU11065

Comment: Yes men! thank you so much! That's what am i looking for!